# Setting up jasmine-maven-plugin failures to make jenkins unstable

Tags: maven, jenkins, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

I'd like to configure [jasmine-maven-plugin](http://searls.github.com/jasmine-maven-plugin/) to make jenkins unstable if a test fails but the only options appear to be:

1. set haltOnFailure true and have failures break the build
2. set haltOnFailure false and have failures reported in the logs but the build succeeds.

Is there a way to check the logs post-test and mark the build unstable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam Hasler's answer only works for freestyle Jenkins jobs. We use Maven jobs and this configuration option of the JUnit Jenkins plugin is unavailable for Maven jobs. So I was looking for a more universal solution.

What we did in order to get it working is to reconfigure the Jasmine Maven plugin so as to

- no longer halt the build upon test failures and
- write the Jasmine test reports to *target/surefire-reports* where Jenkins expects to find them. This has the additional advantage that we now also see the failed Jasmine test in the build job alongside our Java tests.

```xml
<haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
<jasmineTargetDir>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</jasmineTargetDir>
```

Now our build jobs are yellow (unstable) as expected, no longer red (failed).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself!

I had to configure jenkins to also look at the jasmine junit report:

under `Publish JUnit test result report` add `**/TEST-jasmine.xml` to `Test report XMLs`, comma separated if there is something there already:

`**/TESTS-TestSuites.xml,**/TEST-jasmine.xml`

Comment: I do not understand the answer. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry, neither do I now... :(

Comment: Thanks for accepting my other answer which I found in the meantime. I am really happy with the new solution now.